# Make PagedListPager use UK date format for parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

How does the [PagedListPager](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList) interpret date parameters because it seems to be treating `01/04/2003` as 1st April 2003 for one pager item and 4th January 2003 for another.

In my razor mark-up I'm displaying 2 text boxes to allow the user to select a start and end date for a report, I've got the pager at the bottom to allow the user to move through the results. Now the weird thing is that if I enter a date such as 1st April 2003 and return my results the pager at the bottom will set the date to 4th January when paging to one of the other pages. However once on, for example page 2, the reverse is true. It will take the 4th January and convert it to 1st April...? I just need to be consistent here - but actually have no problem with hardcoding UK date format for this.

```
<label for="StartDate">Start Date: </label> 
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" 
       value="@ViewBag.StartDate" />  
<label for="EndDate">End Date:</label> 
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" 
       value="@ViewBag.EndDate" />
```

The ViewBag is there so the values entered are persisted when paging between the results and the PagedListPager uses the same values

```
@Html.PagedListPager(@Model, page => Url.Action("ReadyBox", 
        new { page = page, 
        sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, 
        startDate = ViewBag.StartDate, 
        endDate = ViewBag.EndDate }), 
        PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast)
```

and the controller for this is

```
public ActionResult ReadyBox(string sortOrder, int? page, 
                             DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    ViewBag.NameSortParam = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortOrder) ? "Name desc" : "";
    ViewBag.DateSortParam = sortOrder == "Date" ? "Date desc" : "Date";

    int pageNumber = page ?? 1;

    if (startDate == null)
        startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);

    if (endDate == null)
        endDate = DateTime.Now;

    ViewBag.StartDate = ((DateTime)startDate).ToShortDateString();
    ViewBag.EndDate = ((DateTime)endDate).ToShortDateString();

    // rest of the controller
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GET requests I would recommend you using an InvariantCulture format:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(
    Model, 
    page => Url.Action(
        "ReadyBox", 
        new { 
            page = page, 
            sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, 
            startDate = ViewBag.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 
            endDate = ViewBag.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") 
        }
    ), 
    PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast
)
```

The default model binder always uses invariant culture format when binding parameters from a GET request and the current culture when binding parameters from a POST request. You can read more about it in [`this blog post`](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx).